# Unable to mount Truecrypt volume

Tags: dual-boot, mount, encryption

I got one HDD with two OS in it, Ubuntu and Window 7. I made a mistake to install the first one since the second one is TrueCrypt encrypted. Now I can't access Windows 7 files anymore.

So I decided to use TrueCrypt GUI to access that partition but it tells me **Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume**. I don't get it, I got the correct Password, and I'm doing it on the right partition.

I tried **Use keyfiles** and **Mount partition using system encryption (pret-boot auth)** (it was the case) but no result.

```
/dev/sda1                  2048   2101247   2099200    1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2    *          2101248 388007935 385906688  184G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3             388009982 470624255  82614274 39,4G  5 Étendue
/dev/sda4             470624256 495912959  25288704 12,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5             388009984 470624255  82614272 39,4G 83 Linux
```

I want to access `/dev/sda2`. I'm currently working on it with Parted Magic. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To access the files inside a volume encrypted with TrueCrypt you need to decrypt it with a compatible application and/or driver. For TrueCrypt there are two options in Ubuntu.

## Use TrueCrypt for Linux

… or, since TrueCrypt itself is discontinued, one of its forks. The most popular and well maintained one appears to be VeraCrypt so I'll go with that.

1. To install

   - either go to https://www.veracrypt.fr/, download the most recent VeraCrypt release for Ubuntu, unpack the TAR archive with your favourite archive manager and run the GUI setup tool for your system architecture with super-user privileges, e. g.

     ```
     sudo ./veracrypt-1.19-setup-gui-x64
     ```
   - or install from a PPA (with the usual security implication):

     ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install veracrypt
     ```
2. Start VeraCrypt through the dash, the application menu, or the command-line (`veracrypt`).
3. Mount the encrypted volume like you would with TrueCrypt in Windows.

### Use the TrueCrypt compatibility mode of `cryptsetup`

```
sudo cryptsetup open <name> /dev/sda2 --type tcrypt <options>
```

You can choose `<name>` freely.

> `<options>` can be [`--key-file`, `--tcrypt-hidden`, `--tcrypt-system`, `--readonly`, `--test-passphrase`].

<sup>More info in the [manual of `cryptsetup(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/cryptsetup.8.html)</sup>

If you supply the correct key file and/or pass phrase you'll get a new virtual device at `/dev/mapper/<name>` which you can mount like any other file system through file managers, partition managers, or on the command-line (e. g. `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/mapper/<name> --filesystem-type ntfs`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure the password is correct, the only explanation to your issue is that something has damaged the TrueCrypt volume header on the disk. This may have happened during the Ubuntu installation.

From [Recover a TrueCrypt Volume](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Recover_a_TrueCrypt_Volume):

> The standard volume header uses the first 512 bytes of the TrueCrypt container. It contains the master keys needed to decrypt the volume. If the header gets corrupted or the container reformatted, TrueCrypt will display `Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume`. Using a backup of the volume header is the only possibility to recover the data.

Using another application that can decrypt TrueCrypt volumes to access the TrueCrypt volume that is unable to be mounted without backing up the TrueCrypt volume first is another mistake, because this can make the TrueCrypt volume even harder to mount by corrupting or damaging the TrueCrypt volume header. For this reason whatever strategy you choose to recover the data in the TrueCrypt volume except for using TrueCrypt itself should begin by backing up the entire TrueCrypt volume.

During the process of preparing the encryption of a system partition/drive, TrueCrypt requires that you create a so-called TrueCrypt Rescue Disk. If you have a TrueCrypt Rescue Disk, you can use it to rescue the TrueCrypt volume. However if you don't have a TrueCrypt Rescue Disk, you should backup the entire hard drive before you meddle with it.